# Unable to use ascii_letters imported from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm unable to print the alphabets that are imported from `string` module.
The error I get is:

> 'str' object is not callable

[image]

CODE:

```py
import string

a = string.ascii_letters()
print(a)
```

Comment: `string.ascii_letters` is a global attribute of the `string` module(it is not a function)

Comment: Should be: `a = string.ascii_letters; print(a)` with no `()` on the `ascii_letters`

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = string.ascii_letters
print(a)
```

`ascii_letters` is not a method (hence you cannot use the `()` to "call" it).